# Restore MapState after Taskmanager failure

Tags: apache-flink

I have to Aggregate the count/sum on event stream for various entities. event logs(json str) are received from kafka and populate map entityname as key and value is count of the selective attriibutes as json str .

MapState sourceAggregationMap = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(sourceAggregationDesc);

for each event stream repopulate the value .

problem is whenever task manager gets stopped or failed and when the task manager gets restarted map state is not getting reinitialized / restored . again count starts from 0.

using Apache flink 1.6.0 state.backend: rocksdb

Comment: Did you enable checkpointing?

Comment: Yes I have enabled checkpointing . So in docker they stopped task manager and restarted taskmanager . Do we have option to specify checkpoint file

Comment: You have to configure a persistent (distributed) file system to which the checkpoints are written.

Comment: When i restart taskmanager in docker can I sepecify option -s "<CHK>" similar to job manager . so that it picks from where it left . 
Now when i start in docker the states are not restored.

Comment: For recovery the complete job is restarted which is coordinated by the JobManager. There is no need to pass a parameter to the TM process. This seems to require a bit more discussion which does not work well on Stack Overflow. Please reach out to the Flink user mailing list to discuss the issue.